# How to hide geometry columns from queries in psql?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, psql

Using psql on a PostGIS database, you get a lot of this:

```
> SELECT * FROM blah;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
26FC5C6240830B7CBCC50A42C094FE21A7F65C6240D47966DFBB0A42C0C612132AF15C6240CA8815B2B60A42C0DB01CFA4EA5C6240FF773FCCB00A42C0E9171D77E75C6240126C4FD5AC0A42C09EF6C98EE35C62408EC0D6A7A70A42C0998DC688E15C6240
93CFF86240776BA837F4C63EC096DBFDF7CEF8624035811033F5C63EC003C63A22CDF8624003807C6CFFC63EC0BC395F63CCF86240B80A346800C73EC07CC6C51EC8F86240E4608A0014C73EC0BBA85A2EC2F8624035E9196F29C73EC0D3A40FBBC1F86240
59ABE36240A742B32031F140C02FBD5672B0E362408C64138917F140C0706C10C2B0E36240AB9E994E15F140C0F9B38052B2E36240497062C90EF140C05D05D35EB4E362408BC1890906F140C092EECBBFB4E362405D2FD14904F140C0A391AE1DB5E36240
```

...

Is there any convenient way to never show the conentents of geometry columns?

Comment: (it's called hex-encoded [WKB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text))

Comment: This is the same question on DBA.SE http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/1957/1528

Comment: Some [relevant discussion about cross-site duplicates on meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262292/479863), I'm not certain that my close vote (which is more of a "move this and mark as duplicate when it gets there" vote) is The Right Thing here.

Comment: yeah, I pondered gis.se and dba.se. FWIW, my question is slightly different in that it's specifically about psql, the command line tool - rather than Postgres generically. If I was using a graphical tool, it wouldn't be an issue. (It also means that psql-specific answers are fine.)

Comment: Well, from reading that discussion, it seems unlikely there is a way. So probably creating a view with N-1 columns is the most practical way.

Comment: I agree that your question is psql-specific (and thus different), but yeah a view seems to be the best approach. But it would be nice to have some better options with psql, even having something like a MAX_WORDS_PER_COLUMN (like pgAdmin has). It could be worthwhile asking on [pgsql-hackers](http://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-hackers/).